# Need to modify the below data structure to have it sorted

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Need suggestion on how below data structure can be sorted based on 'popularity'?

```
Data_structure={0:{name:"xxx",popularity:100},1:{name:"yyy", popularity:90}}
```

Comment: if you need the right order, try collections.OrderedDict()

Comment: It is now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: Why aren't you using a list instead of the outer dict?

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` builtin function in python accepts a `key` argument that expects a function. So basically, you can do that:

```py
data = {0: {"name": "xxx", "popularity": 100},1: {"name":"yyy", "popularity":90}}
data = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]["popularity"]))
```

Comment: Yes, assuming python>3.6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 1):

Using [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to cover both Python **2.x** and Python **3.x**:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data = {0: {"name": "xxx", "popularity": 100}, 1: {"name":"yyy", "popularity":90}}

ordered_data = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['popularity']))
print(ordered_data)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
OrderedDict([(1, {'popularity': 90, 'name': 'yyy'}), (0, {'popularity': 100, 'name': 'xxx'})])
```

Comment: You just copy/paste my answer, add an OrderedDict (which is useless for py3.6+) and claim it yours?

Comment: Relax sir, I did not copy your answer, your answer is specifically for Python 3.x where as mine covers both Python 2.x and 3.x. cheers